# Best way to handle redirects using HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: android, redirect, httpurlconnection

I use HTTPUrlConnection to download compressed JSON information.

Normally this works fine, but my app is used a lot in Airports and some sessions end up with 302 HttpResponses, basically redirects for users login to airport wifi etc. In these situations I bring up a message explaining the issue. Examples of redirects would be www.btopenzone.com.

Is there any way to handle this myself and still get my JSON information downloaded?

Any advice on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, sometimes I get a normal 200 httpresponse but I get a JSON error because HTML is being returned, examples seem to be related to www.boingo.com

Again, all help welcome.

Comment: "Is there any way to handle this myself and still get my JSON information downloaded?" -- what do you mean by this? You cannot log into BTOpenZone on the user's behalf very readily. You can find out if a network sign-on scenario occurred (see "Network Sign-On" in [the `HttpUrlConnection` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)). You can prompt the user to handle the sign-on, then have the user indicate that it is time to retry the operation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Once the user signs in though, will that redirection always stop? After the user logs in, will the 302 http responses stop and revert to 200 http responses?

Comment: For any hotel system I have used, HTTP operations behave normally after the authentication or purchase or whatever. There could be some stupid systems out there that trigger perpetual redirects, I suppose.

Comment: It would be great if we could rely on the HTTP Response values to let us know when there is a redirect. I see examples of where I get a response of 200, but then when I download the information, it is actually HTML rather than JSON. It seems to be when they display a splash page, I have to rely on JSON exceptions to let me know what is going on.

Comment: So, what is the best way to communicate to the user that they need to do something, a simple dialog box or is there more I can do?

Comment: That's a UI/UX question. Whether you use a dialog, or a crouton, or a notification, or do something as part of your main UI (e.g., update the empty view for a `ListFragment` to indicate the nature of the problem) is up to you and depends a lot on the nature of your app.

Comment: Thanks a million Commonsware.